# How to fill the YOAST SEO Meta data when creating a post using API

Tags: wordpress, seo, yoast

I'm trying to insert meta description for my Wordpress post, but the meta-description is always empty.

This is my code:

```
post_data = {
        'title': title,
        'content':  markdown.markdown(content),
        'slug': slug,
        'status': 'publish',
        'yoast_meta' : {
            'yoast_wpseo_metadesc' : meta_description
         },
        'author': author_id,
        'categories': [category_id],  # Assign the category ID to the post
        'meta': {
            'meta_description': meta_description,
        },
    }
```

I'm not sure if the field name is the right one or if Yoast even supports feeding the meta description from API.

Answer (score 3):

Had the same issue. If you install the following plugin: https://github.com/ChazUK/wp-api-yoast-meta

You can do the following:

```
try {
  const response = await wp.posts().create({
    title: "Your Post Title",
    content: "Your post content",
    status: "publish",
    yoast_meta: {
      yoast_wpseo_title: "Your SEO title",
      yoast_wpseo_metadesc: "Your SEO description",
    },
  });
  console.log(response.id);
} catch (error) {
  console.error(error);
};
```

Comment: Very helpful, I tried to do this with api rest yoast but I noticed that their api rest it's just for READ ONLY, so this is a very helpful solution, I would like to add that if you want to set focus keyword use 'yoast_wpseo_focuskw'.

Comment: @MarcosSelin I'm joining the party a bit late, but I can confirm the above method is working for me.

Comment: Hello. The plugin works great. But it was published 6 years ago and I was wondering now if there is a solution without using any plugin?

Answer (score 1):

I've been breaking my head over setting the SEO Titles and descriptions. I found two methods (one that works for all content and one which works for posts/pages/categories)

#### Method 1: (Works for all content like tags, categories, CPT's, pages etc.)

There is a [plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-rest-yoast-meta/) that manages the theme's `functions.php` you are using and adds the relevant filters for the fields you can use through the WP Rest API. After installation you can use the following structure to make API Calls when creating something:

```
post_data = {
  "title": "Your Title",
  "content": "Your Content",
  "yoast_meta": {
    "yoast_wpseo_title": "SEO Title",
    "yoast_wpseo_metadesc": "SEO Desc",
  },
  ... # Other fields
}
```

#### Method 2: (Works for pages/categories)

If you wanna customize the fields you want to use, I would recommend going into the theme's `functions.php` and adding filters to fields you wanna use. The most important thing is here is that you have to map your custom field to `_yoast_wpseo_title` and `_yoast_wpseo_metadesc`. Other fields also follow a similar format like `_yoast_wpseo_robots`, I have not tested this out but I am pretty sure it will work as long as you add the filters in the `functions.php`. An example API Call now would be:

```
post_data = {
  "title": "Your Title",
  "content": "Your Content",
  ... # Other fields
  "meta": {
    "_yoast_wpseo_title": "SEO Title",
    "_yoast_wpseo_metadesc": "SEO Desc",
    ... # Other fields
  }
}
```

I have not tested out Method 2 for tags as my project didn't require it. But I think when setting the filters you can use `post_tag` to map the fields.

Answer (score -2):

You need to use the `_yoast_wpseo_metadesc` key instead of `yoast_wpseo_metadesc`, as this is the actual key used by Yoast SEO to store the meta description.

```
post_data = {
    'title': title,
    'content': markdown.markdown(content),
    'slug': slug,
    'status': 'publish',
    'meta': {
        '_yoast_wpseo_metadesc': meta_description
    },
    'author': author_id,
    'categories': [category_id],
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work.. Do you have a documentation for this?

Comment: can confirm, I've been stuck in here for few hours, this doesn't work